# Why can I only Swipe my Custom View Image Once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How's it going?  I have an IBOutlet UIImageView with an IBAction swipe gesture function but I can only swipe the object once.  Essentially, there's a 5x5 gameboard along with 2 stone-like objects that I can continuously swipe around the board.  Swipe once, the stone-like object moves till it reaches the board boundary.

Here's some of the code (for swiping down on stone _one)

```
    - (IBAction)swipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
         NSLog(@"Swipe Right");
         // Get the view I'm interacting with, in this case, _one
         UIView *view = recognizer.view;
         if (view == _one) {
             NSLog(@"Got it 2");
             [self moveOne:CGPointMake(-1, 0) withView:view];
         } else if (view == _two) {
             NSLog(@"Got it 2.5");
             [self moveTwo:CGPointMake(-1, 0) withView:view];
         }
    }

    - (void)moveOne:(CGPoint)direction withView:(UIView*)stoneView {
         NSLog(@"Got it 5");
         // Bunch of code for getting new position
         // .
         // .
         // .
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f
                               delay:0.0f
                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                          animations:^{
                              CGRect rect = stoneView.frame;
                              rect.origin.x = _currentCol*61.5;
                              rect.origin.y = _currentRow*61.5;
                              stoneView.frame = rect;
                          }
                          completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                              NSLog(@"Done finally");
                          }];
    }
```

Ok so when I run this, and check out the output, my program makes it to "Done finally" in the Log.  But I can only swipe the stones once.  Imagine 2048 except you only get to swipe the number '2' tile once and then never interact with the game again.

The gesture recognizer instances for each stone are created in viewDidLoad{} in ViewController.m, same as the swipe and move methods.  Why can't I swipe multiple times?  Should there be some update in the 'completion:' block of the animate method?

-Thanks   let me know if you need more info

Comment: After swipe one time check the recogniser of view whether it is showing swipe gesture recogniser or not.

Comment: Once you swipe.After swipe check the gesture of that view. So you will get idea whether that view has swipe gesture or not

Comment: How does that help?  My view is declared in @implementation{}:  IBOutlet UIImageView* _one;          It is always connected, and programmatically it has all swipe instances assigned to it.

Comment: For that you have to debug the code.  and check gesture of view (view which you want to move)

Comment: Where would I set a break point?  Or is that not the correct way?  Sorry, I'm also quite new with this.